# How do I draw a line in Openlayer and draw a point on it?

Tags: gis, openlayers-3

How do I draw lines on the openlayer and draw points on the line through the miles?

I can draw a line on the openlayer, but I don't know how to draw a point online based on the distance from the distance.

Answer (score 2):

Draw your line, then serialize the drawn line line to GeoJSON (using `ol.format.GeoJSON`, then use Turf library `along` [function](http://turfjs.org/docs/#along) and then reuse the point returned from this Turf function to add it to OpenLayers

```
// GeoJSON sample line
var geojson = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        0.142822265625,
        48.03769224746972
      ],
      [
        -0.230712890625,
        47.73562905149295
      ],
      [
        -0.3131103515625,
        47.55428670127958
      ],
      [
        -0.98876953125,
        47.42065432071318
      ],
      [
        -1.6149902343749998,
        47.21956811231547
      ],
      [
        -1.1370849609375,
        46.558860303117164
      ],
      [
        -0.340576171875,
        46.34692761055676
      ],
      [
        -0.6756591796875,
        45.78284835197676
      ],
      [
        -0.494384765625,
        45.10454630976873
      ],
      [
        -0.5877685546875,
        44.78183504339988
      ]
    ]
  }
};
// Convert GeoJSON feature line to OpenLayers feature
var lineFeature = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeature(geojson);

// Convert OpenLayers line feature to GeoJSON feature, you may want later
// to change reproject coordinates to display it on the map
var geojsonFromLineFeature = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).writeFeature(lineFeature);

// Calculate point position 85 miles away from the point
// coordinates beginning along the line
var pointFrom85Miles = turf.along(line1, 85, {units: 'miles'});

// Convert GeoJSON point to OpenLayers point feature
var pointFrom85MilesFeature = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).write(pointFrom85Miles);
```

I've tried using OpenLayers `getCoordinateAtM` but the result were really not aligned with Turf.
Below, I've done calculation of length for the GeoJSON line and they are too different, so interpolation with `getCoordinateAtM` is not better... (maybe because it works on projected plane)

```
// Units are in degrees
feature.getGeometry().getLength()
// Return 5.359842138525585

// Units are in degrees
turf.length(geojson, {units: 'degrees'});
// Return 4.477214098875635
```